# Adding UI Tab Bar on pages that are not linked

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am currently working on a project which uses a tab bar controller. I was wondering if there was a way to show the tab bar on pages that it is not linked to, ie. a page that you cant navigate to using the tab bar controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that won't be possible, as tab bar controller has only those objects which are part of its architecture.

What you can do is maybe use a toolbar on the other page which looks similar to tab bar controller but gives the same look and feel. And then tapping the items on the toolbar, you can write a delegate which will know what item you clicked and open that particular tab on your actual tab controller.

Comment: Ok cool, that is unfortunate, but it's good to know as early as possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the system UITabBarController, you can not do this, but if you really need it, you can make a custom one. You can post some screenshot with the effect you want, I can give you some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, I managed to solve my problem.

What I did was add a tab bar and the tab items on the other pages that were not linked. After this, I just wrote a simple delegate for the tab bar itself. This would let me navigate to the TabBarController on the specific tab using a case statement to check the name of the button I pressed, eg. move to the home page when the "home" button is pressed.

Regards,